# PHP While Loop returning 1 result should be returning 15?

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I wrote a function that should return all users in the database.  It's printing the array, but it's only printing one result.  Why is it doing this?  I surrounded it in a while loop and put a limit in my query...

Code:

```
function getAllUsers() {

global $PDO;

    $stm = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `bid` DESC LIMIT 15");

        $stm->execute();

            while($Array = $stm->fetch()) {
                return print_r($Array);
            }

}
```

Comment: using return in a loop will only result to one result.

Comment: You can wait and look at the answers below, or do yourself a favor and learn some basics on certain channels like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lb0NYODtGr4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) :

```
$data = $stm->fetchAll()
foreach ($data as $item ) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

Comment: you can use the foreach loop instead of the while too

Comment: one hand washes the other @FouadFodail =)

Answer (score 1):

use the foreach loop instead of the while and fetchAll() instead of the fetch():

```
foreach ($stm->fetchAll() as $arr) {
   print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: dont use return, in loop it will only loop once

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllUsers() {

   global $PDO;

   $stm = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `bid` DESC LIMIT 15");
   $stm->execute();

   $var = array();

   while($Array = $stm->fetch()) {

     $var = $Array;

  }

 return $var;

 }
```